# Is there a better way to do this python code?

Tags: python

Looking at this snippet of python code I wrote:

```
return map(lambda x: x[1], 
           filter(lambda x: x[0] == 0b0000, 
                  my_func(i)
                 )
          )
```

(Hoping it's self-explanatory)

I'm wondering if python has a better way to do it?

I learned python several months ago, wrote a couple scripts, and haven't used it much since. It puts me in a weird spot for learning because I know enough to do what I want but don't have the newbie instinct to find the "proper" way. I'm hoping this question will put me back on course...

Comment: I assume `my_func()` returns a list of lists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want a list comprehension:

```
[x[1] for x in my_func(i) if x[0] == 0]
```

List comprehensions are an extremely common Python idiom.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
return [x[1] for x in my_func(i) if x[0] == 0b0000]
```

Many people would call that "better" as its a little shorter and more obvious.

(I would be tempted to consider turning it into a simple loop and if statement.  Functional programming is nice but simple loops are nice too.)

Comment: How is a `for` loop either better or more obvious? The list comprehension is far more readable once you get used to it.

Comment: Are you meant to be assigning `x[0]` ? or is that meant to be `==` ?

Comment: @Russell Dias: He means `==` because its a syntax error otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing in Python 3.x, then you could write an efficient generator expression such as this: `return (x[1] for x in my_func(i) if not x[0])`

Comment: There is a difference between `map` in Python 2.x and 3.x. Last time I checked, `map` in 2.x returned a list but acts like a generator in 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.x you can use unpacking to avoid using `x[0]` and `x[1]`.
Also you may consider returning a generator expression instead of a list-comprehension if you only want to loop over the result once:

```
return (y for x,y,*z in my_func(i) if x == 0b0000)
```